# Result from wp_send_json adds line feed

Tags: php, ajax, json

I've got a local Windows stack running AMPPS at 5.4.35 and my code runs fine but when I deploy to my Bluehost server running PHP 5.4.28 the execution of wp_send_json is different.

```
wp_send_json( array('error' => 'Please enter a valid postcode.', 'errorFieldType'=>'postcode') );
```

Works fine on Windows but on Bluehost, if I debug in Chrome there is a line feed added to the beginning of the response. If I open it in Chrome's console I get this.

```
response
"
{"error":"Please enter a valid postcode.","errorFieldType":"postcode"}"
```

On Windows alert(response.error); shows the error, on Bluehost I get "undefined".

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: My guess is, coming from Windows, my php script has carriage return-line feeds, where as unix only has line feeds. The php interpreter is giving me back a left over carriage return in my output which is put at the beginning of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was tricky. This was the offending code that was generated a line feed to the response.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_display_event_info', 'DisplayEventInfoBox');
?>

<?php
function displayStepHeader($isValid, $pos)
```

I changed it to

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_display_event_info', 'DisplayEventInfoBox');

function displayStepHeader($isValid, $pos)
```

and all is well. I have no idea why that was an issue but how I tracked it down may be useful for someone else. I simply put echo 'a'; between the function definitions until the first character I received was an 'a' and not char 10 (line feed).

This was also caused "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" because the first character sometimes wasn't < but a line feed.

Hopes this helps someone else out one day...